# what views and controls to use ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new to ios. I need your advice.
I saw some implementation of the thing i need on my app:

[image]
[image]

I know how to use textFields. I need the below layout(black marker, the  blue text is translated as "Ready").

Can you tell me how it's called in ios, and is it custom or it's some standart view from the box(ios sdk)? and maybe if you have some links where can i find the implementation. thanks.

Comment: [UIPickerView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerView_Class/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)It can be done using native UI component

2)You need to creat a custom view where  you need add two views first one is `UIPickerView` & second one is `UIToolBar`

3)Below is the sample code to for adding toolbar

4)Make sure your toolbar frame x will be (total height - pickerView hieght -toolBar height)

```
        UIToolbar *keyboardToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, calcultedHeight, self.view.frame.size.width,44)];
 //here adding your left buttons
       UIBarButtonItem *btnDone = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneButtonAction)];
 //here we are adding flexible space
       UIBarButtonItem *btnFlexible = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
//here your ready button
      UIBarButtonItem *btnReady = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(readyButtonAction)];
        [keyboardToolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:btnFlexible, btnDone,btnReady, nil]];
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for a [UIPickerView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerview).

Something that looks like this:

[image: a PickerView]
<sub>(source: [apoorvmote.com](http://blog.apoorvmote.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/picker-w-1-column.png))</sub>